# ogr2ogr batch append/update multiple gml files to postgres DB- how to skip the failed feature and log erros to a file

Tags: postgis, gdal, gml, os-mastermap, batch

My task is to append/update features to a postgis table by importing multiple gml files that contain os mastermap topography data. I've created a batch file that contains the script below and it worked ok, except it tends to fail when trying to import too many gml files all at once.

```
//the folder where all the gml files are stored//
set dirgml= C:\data\os_mastermap 

set app=ogr2ogr
set opt=-update -append -progress
set dst=-f "PostgreSQL" PG="host='my host' port='my port' dbname='my dbname' user='my username' password='my password' active_schema=public"

//batch import all gml files under the folder set as 'dirgml'//
for %%G IN ('dir/b %dirgml%\*) do %app% %opt% %dst% "%%G"
```

I run this file from OSGeo4W Shell and it works perfectly fine if I only upload small number of files, say under 10. However, if I try to batch import more than 10 files that contains large gml file(s), it tends to fail.

I am aware that you can use a command -skipfailures to contine after failed features, however does it create an error log? so that when the batch task is done, then I can retry importing those failed features either manually or batch load in a small quantity. Even better solution is automate this all; for example, after importing the last gml file, look to see if any errors are logged - if it is, importing failed features again?

Comment: -skipfailures does not create log. I would use -skipfailures and then compare the values of some unique attribute in source data and converted data. Feature ID is a good candidate. Automation with some Python coding should not be too hard for someone who know GDAL and Python. You seem to just append new rows, not to edit existing ones. With the latter approach catching the failures would be a bit harder. Consider to add an attribute like `last_update` into your data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. sound like adding an attribute may be a good idea. I guess you need to use -addfields ?  Though I know python qute well, very new to GDAL...is it possible also to add an attribute of the name of gml file into my data?